# select NULL and false but not true in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i an new in vb.net sql and what i am asking may be silly question. I have a table in sql server 2005 and a column name activated. this column contain NULL, true or false.

I want to select only NULL or false values. How can i do this?

Comment: always mention what you have tried till now.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The selection should be done on the SQL Server's side. Your query should look like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE activated = 0 OR activated is NULL
```

The above assumes that the column `activated` is of an integral or a `BIT` data type.

Note: it may be tempting to use a seemingly equivalent `WHERE activated <> 1` condition. This would be incorrect, though, because comparisons of `NULL` values to anything result in a `NULL`, so the rows with `activated = NULL` would be excluded.

Answer (score 2):

With SQL's 3-valued logic, comparisons for NULL need to be done using the `IS NULL` operator... the check for false can be done with `=`:

```
SELECT YourColumn
FROM YourTable
WHERE 
  YourColumn IS NULL 
  OR YourColumn = 0
```

Answer (score 2):

You should be able to do a coalesce on the field to get it to false if it is null. A coalesce statement checks to see if the first parameter is null, if it is it returns the value in the second parameter. There would be two solutions:

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE COALESCE(activated,'false') <> 'true'`
```

--OR--

```
SELECT *
FROM MyTable
WHERE activated = 'false' or activated is null
```

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes you have to see it to believe...

```
PRINT '0 = 0'       ; IF 0 = 0        PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
PRINT '0 = 1'       ; IF 0 = 1        PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
PRINT '0 = NULL'    ; IF 0 = NULL     PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
PRINT '1 = NULL'    ; IF 1 = NULL     PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
PRINT 'NULL = NULL' ; IF NULL = NULL  PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
PRINT 'NULL IS NULL'; IF NULL IS NULL PRINT 'true' ELSE PRINT 'false';PRINT '';
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE isnull(activated, 0) = 0
```

Answer (score 0):

For checking NULL you have to use the keyword `"IS NULL"` and for false `=0` like below

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE activated = 0 OR activated is NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

The SQL way is to use IS TRUE or similar:

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE activated = 0 IS NOT FALSE
```

Answer (score 0):

@girgen

Hi,
in Sql server this query is not true.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable WHERE activated = 0 IS NOT FALSE
```

This query is for MySql Query not in Sql server. in sql server you can use IS NOT NULL.