# SQL selecting values with Null and 0 values from range null, 0 & 1

Tags: sql, sql-server

One of the columns returned by a T-SQL query has one of these three values

```
NULL, 0, 1
```

I am trying to filter out the 1 values, but when I use these clause:

Query:

```
select foo 
from dbo.table1
where ..
```

Clause:

1. `where foo <> 1`: returns only the data with 0 values in the column
2. `Where foo is null`: returns only the null values in the column
3. `where foo in (Null, 0)`: returns only the data with 0 values in the column

What is the correct method to filter out the data?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21266842/select-null-and-false-but-not-true-in-sql

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since there are only 3 values, this is enough:

```
where isnull(foo, 0) <> 1
```

or:

```
where isnull(foo, 0) = 0
```

Comment: I wouldn't really recommend this as the answer. This will cause the query to be non-SARGable, which could have severe performance implications.

Comment: @Larnu do you consider coalesce() sargable?

Comment: no. Neither `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` (which is just a shortcut `CASE` expression) are SARGable.

Comment: @Larnu Then why did you post this comment here and not to the other answer too?

Comment: Gordan has a SARGable answer as well: `foo <> 1 or foo is null`. That won't have the same performances problems that using `ISNULL` or `COALESCE` will have, as the indexes on the table(s) can still be made use of.

Comment: @Larnu and a **not** sargable one too, right? Anyone seeing the simplicity of only 1 condition would choose that and not `foo <> 1 or foo is null`, right? Why did you not post a comment there too stating that the first one should be the right choice?

Comment: My main reason here, is that the OP has actually accepted this as the answer.

Comment: @Larnu and I wonder if the OP changes his mind will you be here to post the same comment? I wonder...

Comment: The comments here have covered everything @forpas. There's no need to duplicate the conversation under Gordan's answer. If you feel it's relevant though, please do raise the concern there as well.

Comment: @Larnu Yes here and not not there.

Answer (score 5):

In SQL Server, you can do:

```
where foo <> 1 or foo is null
```

Or, if you know that there really are only three values, something like:

```
where coalesce(foo, -1) <> 1
```

SQL Server does not have a `NULL`-safe comparison.  Standard SQL supports:

```
where foo is distinct from 1
```

but that is not available in SQL Server.